# Python convert b3dm to gltf

Tags: python, 3d, gltf

I'm trying to convert a b3dm file to gltf using Python.

a b3dm file should be very similar to a gltf, but since the file is in raw bytes I cannot easily see how to make a gltf of it, by updating it's header.

The goal is to be able to use the pygltflib package as follows:

```html
import pygltflib


b3dm_file = '/the/input.b3dm'
out_file = '/the/result.glb'

#######some conversion step here


gltf = pygltflib.GLTF2.load(out_file)
```

I have had a look at py3dtiles, but that package already crashes when running the first example.

```
import py3dtiles

py3dtiles.__version__

from py3dtiles import TileContentReader
```

giving version 1.0.2 and

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TileContentReader' from 'py3dtiles' (/home/daniel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py3dtiles/__init__.py)
```

Has anyone successfully converted b3dm files to gltf files using Python?

Answer (score 0):

The Py3dtiles 1.0.2 version is very old. Can you try this below snippet with the last version (v7.0.0) ?

```
from pathlib import Path

from py3dtiles.tileset.content import read_binary_tile_content


b3dm = read_binary_tile_content(Path('/the/input.b3dm'))
gltf = b3dm.body.gltf
with Path("/the/result.gltf").open('wb') as f:
    f.write(gltf.to_array())
```

Since the gltf support by Py3dtiles is not complete, it may not work. Btw, there are discussions about using `pygltflib` directly in Py3dtiles (see this [issue](https://gitlab.com/py3dtiles/py3dtiles/-/issues/184))